# Solution to Laplace's equation on the disk

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading through this document http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124B/lecs/lec10.pdf, which arrives at the following series solution to Laplace's equation on the disk:

$$u(r, \theta)=\frac{A_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^{n}\left(A_{n} \cos n \theta+B_{n} \sin n \theta\right).$$

1. **Why do we sum up all the eigenfunctions? How do we know this gives a solution? (I know very little about diff. equations, and I'm just looking for a brief explanation here.)**
2. **What is the nature of the convergence of this series? Can we pick $A_n$ and $B_n$ that decay rapidly enough so that  it converge uniformly on every compact subset?**

Comment: In response to your first question, you need to sum the solutions due to the principle of superposition. This says that if you have two linearly independent solutions to a linear differential equation, then the sum of the solutions is also a solution and is the _most_ general solution to the problem. Remember, each fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ yields a solution to the original PDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a formal solution. If you just differentiate termwise ignoring any convergence issues this should come out as an eigenfunction. The tricky part is now to find which coefficients to pick for $A_n$ and $B_n$ to satisfy the boundary conditions and then prove some kind of convergence.

Comment: Ah, I see. So without picking the coefficients, we can't be sure the series even converges?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Sure, pick some sequence of coefficients that explodes sufficiently quickly and this will only converge for $r=0$.

Comment: So, which coefficients is the solution picking? Is it the Fourier coefficients? How do we know that the Fourier series converges?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 I don't know the lecture notes you are reading but you need some kind of boundary conditions on the disk. Most often Dirichlet or Neumann, these give you conditions which determine the $A_n$ and $B_n$.

Comment: I'm referring to the link in my question. This gives a boundary condition, which determines the coefficients, and they seem to be Fourier coefficients. But how do we know this will converge?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if we can pick some coefficients that decay rapidly enough for the series to converge.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Read the lecture notes you linked. In equation (4) the coefficients are determined for the given boundary function $h(\theta)$. It turns out the sequence can be summed explicitly, ie it converges.

Comment: Right, my last question: If we don't have boundary conditions, can we choose some coefficients that decay rapidly enough so that the series converges on every compact subset?

Comment: ??? Do you actually know anything about the solution to the Dirichlet problem in the unit disk, and its relation to Fourier series? This is not just a formal solution, it is _the_ actual solution to the Dirichlet problem (at least for, say, continuous boundary values). And you don't need to justify termwise differentiation to show that the sum is a harmonic function, that's clear from basic results about harmonic functions.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer notwithstanding, this is not "just a formal solution", it is the actual solution to the Dirichlet problem in the unit disk.

Let's say $f\in C(\Bbb T)$ just to keep things simple (that is, $f$ is continuous and has period $2\pi$). We want a function $u(r,t)$ which is continuous in the closed unit disk $\overline D$, is harmonic in $D$, and which equals $f$ on the boundary.

The notation is simpler if we use the "complex" form of Fourier series. Let $$c_n=\hat f(n)\quad(n\in\Bbb Z).$$The $c_n$  are certainly bounded, so the series $$u(r,t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_nr^{|n|}e^{int}$$converges uniformly on compact subsets of the unit disk.

Since $z^n$ and $\left(\overline z\right)^n$ are analytic it follows that the partial sums are harmonic. Since a uniform limit of harmonic functions is harmonic this shows that $u$ is harmonic in the (open) disk.

To answer a question you ask in a comment, the Fourier series of $f$ need *not* converge. But that doesn't matter. Look up "Abel summability" somewhere; it's very well  known that the Fourier series of $f$ *is* uniformmly Abel summable to $f$; this means precisely that $u(r,t)\to f(t)$ uniformly as $r\to 1$.

**About convergence to $f$ at the boundary:** Say $P_r$ is the Poisson kernel. It's  well known and not that hard to prove that the convolution $P_r*f$ tends to $f$ uniformly. It's also well known that $$P_r(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{int}$$(you can calculate that sum explicitly, since it's just the sum of two geometric series), which makes it clear that $$P_r*f(t)=u(r,t).$$

**Come to think of it**, since the title asks about harmonic functions without mentioning boundary values, it may be appropriate to point out that in fact *any* function $u(r,t)$ harmonic in the open unit disk is given by a series as above for some choice of coefficients $c_n$.

Outline of proof: If $u$ is a real-valued harmonic function in the open disk we know there exists a real-valued harmonic function $v$ such that $u+iv$ is analytic. This shows that if $u$ is *any* harmonic function in the disk there exist analytic functions $f$ and $g$ such that $$u=f+\overline g.$$Now $f$ and $g$ are both given by power series...